# Negative number when calling malloc in gdb

Tags: linux, pointers, gdb

```
(gdb) call malloc(5*1024*1024)
$1 = -1223639024
```

It seems that gdb don't know what type malloc will return, so it assumes int. I don't know why. It will be great if someone can give a explaining.

In C code, I can do this:

```
void* (*malloc1)(long)=malloc;
```

then call `malloc1` instead `malloc`. But I don't know how to define such pointer in gdb.

Now my question is, how to define a function pointer to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile with debugging information (using `-g` in case of GCC).  Installing debugging information for the C library (in the packages `libc6-dbg` or `glibc-debuginfo` on many systems) can also help.

You can also cast `malloc` to a function pointer of the right type, like this:

```
(gdb) print ((void * (*) (size_t)) malloc) (5 * 1024 * 1024)
$1 = (void *) 0x7ffff65b2010
```